# Android DatePicker is so slow in WebView

Tags: android, webview, datepicker

Below is the WebView code, which shows the webpage at [here](http://exceptnothing.com/appointment.html). Everything works fine. The date picker is so slow, everything else works fine. It takes like 4-5 seconds to select a date. Any alternatives?

```
public class click extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.click);


        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.exceptnothing.com/appointment.html");

        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    }

}
```

I tried adding **android:hardwareAccelerated="true"** in that activity, same effect still.
I'm a beginner, so simpler code will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are you asking ? A way to improve the speed of that particular date picker in a WebView or any component to pick a date in Android ?

Comment: Improving the speed of the stock date picker in WebView :)

Comment: Mkay, can't help you there, except by saying that this is certainly not "stock". Not sure either why you would include a webview with a form in an Android app instead of replicating that form using Android's native components, since it would mean better UX and less issues with under-performing components.

Comment: I thought to start with Android's own components. Since I'm learning, I felt it tough to implement each elements and the functions. Thought that, HTML could make it easier.
Well if there's no way to speed up, I'd use the components to design a form in app itself. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: If you want to learn Android, going with html in a WebView would not be advisable IMHO. Try the basic training [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html), the [free course on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853), or [Reto Meier's book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118102274.html), although that last one might be a bit outdated now.

Comment: Only this part was done in WebView. The rest of my app involves parsing JSON into ListView. But yeah, I admit, I need to have some basic training first. I'd start one soon. Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

try to checkout android [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html). Its native and fast way to pick a date on android. Also, using webview in android applications is a bad practice to build a well formed user interfaces, it's realy decreases the application performance, look, and user feel. Native android vidgets are always best to do the work. This tutorial will help you if you decide to build your ui as views layout http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

Comment: This is essentially my comments compiled as an answer, and the reason why I didn't post it as an answer is because it doesn't answer the question asked, which was how to speed up the html component in the webview...

Comment: What you suggested helps me if I was building the form with Android components. There are many tutorials and options for that if I had opted that way. I started with WebView, if DatePicker could be optimized for WebView or atleast a method to disable DatePicker so that I could use a jQuery datepicker would be appreciated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You right, i am not english native speaker, so writing an answer for me was leave the head. I was started while you doesn't commented yet, and i am not mentioned you does, before posting, sorry.